# android - Volley response headers

Tags: android, http, android-volley, android-networking

I try to use volley for http request. I tried a request on postman and the response headers are below :

1. Content-Encoding →gzip
2. Content-Length →153
3. Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
4. Date →Fri, 30 Jun 2017 13:36:10 GMT
5. ETag →W/"23-E742p6pP4kakmVh3lok1ww"
6. Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
7. Vary→X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding
8. X-Powered-By →Express, ASP.NET

Volley adds some extra keys and removes `Content-Length` and `Content-Encoding` key. I write keys and values on `parseNetworkResponse` function. Response headers are below :

> Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Date : Fri, 30 Jun 2017 09:05:23 GMT
>   ETag : W/"23-E742p6pP4kakmVh3lok1ww"
>   Server : Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>   Set-Cookie : ARRAffinity=16d81073e15abb17d2faba962adb6504734210ff2b9ff1ddfa770750ac7752e2;Path=/;xxx.net
>   Vary : X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding
>   X-Android-Received-Millis : 1498813523832
>   X-Android-Response-Source : NETWORK 200
>   X-Android-Selected-Protocol : http/1.1
>   X-Android-Sent-Millis : 1498813523632
>   X-Powered-By : Express

Why does it change content? How can I get `Content-Length` and `Content-Encoding`?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the java.net.HttpURLConnection and the getHeaderFieldKey method, then do not forget to check the 0th element from the header according to the [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getHeaderFieldKey(int)):

> Some implementations may treat the 0th header field as special, i.e. as the status line returned by the HTTP server. In this case, **getHeaderField(0) returns the status line**, but getHeaderFieldKey(0) returns null.